# How to iterate two array at same time using ngFor in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have to array objects as payload which comes from node.js, and i store it in different variables and iterate but *ngFor iterate only first loop not second so how to itterate both at same div
status.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let payload1 of payload1;let payload2 of payload2;">
  <h4>{{payload2.username}}</h4>
  <h4>{{payload1.date}}</h4>
</div>
```

status.component.ts

```
payload1 = [];
payload2 = [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.statusService.getStatusDetails(this.statusObj).subscribe(
    (data) => {
      if(data.status == 26){
        this.payload1 = data.payload[0];
        this.payload2 = data.payload[1];
      }
    }
 );
}
```

Comment: If the length of both the arrays are same, you can use `ngFor` on one array while using index to access the other array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not make a single array out of that ?

```
payload = [];
ngOnInit() {
  this.statusService.getStatusDetails(this.statusObj).subscribe(
    (data) => {
      if(data.status == 26){
        this.payload = data.payload[0]
          .map((item, index) => ({ ...item, ...data.payload[1][index] }));
      }
    }
 );
}
```

Snippet proving it works :

```js
const d1 = [
  { id: 0 },
  { id: 1 },
];

const d2 = [
  { name: '0' },
  { name: '1' },
];

const d3 = d1.map((item, index) => ({ ...item, ...d2[index] }));

console.log(d3);
```

You can even build this merged payload if the arrays aren't the same length.

```js
const d1 = [
  { id: 0 },
  { id: 1 },
];

const d2 = [
  { name: '0' },
  { name: '1' },
  { name: '2' },
];

const longest = d1.length > d2.length ? d1 : d2;
const shortest = d1.length <= d2.length ? d1 : d2;

const d3 = longest.map((item, index) => ({ ...item, ...shortest[index] }));

console.log(d3);
```

Angular version :

```
payload = [];
ngOnInit() {
  this.statusService.getStatusDetails(this.statusObj).subscribe(
    (data) => {
      if(data.status == 26){

        const longest = data.payload[0].length > data.payload[1].length ? 
          data.payload[0] : data.payload[1];
        const shortest = data.payload[0].length <= data.payload[1].length ? 
          data.payload[0] : data.payload[1];

        this.payload = longest
          .map((item, index) => ({ ...item, ...shortest[index] }));
      }
    }
 );
}
```

Comment: I'm not a summonable code monkey, but I will help for this one. Please avoid doing that again !

Comment: @AmishaRana totally, if they're the same length and you're sure about that, use the first piece of code.

Answer (score 10):

I think this should work if your payloads are the same length and ordered to match (which your question seems to imply it does)

```
<div *ngFor="let p of payload1;let i = index">
  <h4>{{payload2[i].username}}</h4>
  <h4>{{payload1[i].date}}</h4>
</div>
```